# Local coordinates of a vector field; derivative wrt 1-forms

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, vector-bundles

I am new to studying differential forms, and had questions while going over some readings.

Let $M$ be a $C^{k}$ manifold of dimension $n$, $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow M$ a smooth curve, and $\gamma_s$ a smooth variation of $\gamma$ that agrees with $\gamma$ at $0$ and $1$. We then have that $ \frac{d}{ds}\Big|_{s=0} \gamma_s$ is a globally defined vector field on $\gamma_s(M)$, where the derivative is understood to be an element of the tangent bundle.

Let $(x^1, \ldots, x^n)$ be coordinates of some chart defined on an open subset $\gamma(M) \subset U$ of $M$. I do not understand why $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d}{ds} \Big|_{s=0}x^i(\gamma_s) = \sum_{i=1}^n dx^i (\frac{d}{ds}\Big|_{s=0}\gamma_s)$$ ($dx^i$ is a chart-induced one-form). It is clear to me that the right hand side of the equality is a sum of the local coordinates of the global vector field, but I don't know how to formally manipulate the one-form.

Further, if $p^i = dx^i$, why is the vector field $\sum dx^i(\frac{d}{ds} \Big|_{s=0} \gamma_s) \frac{\partial}{\partial p^i}$ invariant under coordinate transformations? I actually do not properly understand what it means to differentiate with respect to a one-form. I thought about expressing $p^i$ in terms of the holonomic basis induced by the chart to reduce the expression to the global vector field above, but I don't know if this will work.

Please try to make your answer as explicit as possible.

**Important edit**: After a lot of confusion and careful thought, I have determined there is a possibility the material I was reading meant to imply 
$$dx^i (\gamma'(0)) = \frac{d}{dt}(x^i \circ \gamma)(t) \Big|_{t=0}.$$

Would this make things consistent? If yes, is this standard notation?

Comment: The equation $df(X) = X(f)$ (where $X$ is a vector and $f$ is a function) is the definition of how the operator $d$ acts on a function. What book are you learning from? That "differentiating with respect to a differential form" doesn't sound right to me. Rather, if your coordinate charts are $x:M\to\mathbb{R}^{dim M}$the holonomic bases are conformed, for $T^{*}M$, by the differentials of the coordinate functions ($dx^{i}$), and for $TM$ by the (equivalence classes of) differential operators along the curves on which all but one coordinate is kept constant ($\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}$).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the second part of your comment, or perhaps turn it into an answer? We have that $\sum dx^i (\frac{d}{ds} \Big|_{s=0} \gamma_s) \frac{\partial}{\partial p^i} = (\frac{d}{ds} \Big|_{s=0} \gamma_s) \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial p^i}$ by the chain-rule. Are you saying I can argue that the derivative on the right is invariant under change of charts? (Since the vector field is global, this will then suffice.)

Comment: What is your definition of $\frac{\partial}{\partial p^{i}}$? on what objects does it act, and how? You see, the expression would make sense to me if $p$ was a coordinate chart, but you defined $p^i = dx^i$, and I cannot make sense of that.

Comment: Apologies for the late comment. After having a miserable notational nightmare, I think the material I was reading meant to imply $dx^i (\gamma'(0)) = \frac{d}{dt}(x^i \circ \gamma)(t) \Big|_{t=0}$.

Comment: No worries. I think when we are struggling with something is when we learn the most. :) And yes, that is right. I'm glad you solved your issue with notation. Be back soon.